# How is the operator < defined for arrays?

Tags: julia

The operator < has unexpected results.
Operator == has not this problem.
Is this a bug?:

```
julia> [0.01,0.0] < [0.01,2.0]

true
```

Comment: What is the difference in behaviour of `<` vs `==` that you're seeing?

Answer (score 7):

Julia implements a [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) `isless` (see [a related github issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/26189)).

The `isless` vector comparison is implemented [here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/abstractarray.jl#L1716) (which I found using the `@which` macro). It might also be instructive to read about the underlying [`cmp` function in the docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.cmp).

Maybe you want to make an element-wise comparison instead,

```
julia> [0.01,0.0] .< [0.01,2.0]
2-element BitArray{1}:
 false
  true
```

Note the dot in front of the `<` operator, which [broadcasts](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/#man-dot-operators-1) the `isless` comparison.

Otherwise you might want to take a look at [Distances.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distances.jl) for many more metrics.

Comment: Very helpful answer!